# DataPager throws error when querystring value is invalid

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

I am using a Datapager in my project with a ListView control. The Datapager is set to use a querystring value Page, so that a typical URL looks like:

http://mysite.com/Something.aspx?Page=2

The problem is that the ListView throws an ugly error if the pageview is invalid (0, for example). The error is:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: startRowIndex
```

The error originates in the ListView SetPageProperties method.

What is the best way to address this? Can I override the SetPageProperties method in some way, to check the startRowIndex parameter?

**Edit**: here's a very simple page that replicates the error: http://pastebin.com/3Mixy6aT

**Edit 2**: A copy of a simple webapplication project demonstrating the error: http://www.mediafire.com/?8r222x5qim6cwrm

Comment: What behaviour do you expect instead of current (`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`) ?

Comment: I don't mind the exception, but I can't figure out where I would handle this? Page_Init?

Comment: I just ran a simple test and I couldn't reproduce your error.  No matter what garbage I threw at the querystring, the ListView/DataPager gracefully handled everything.  Can you share more code how you are binding the ListView?

Comment: Sure, give me a couple of hours, and I should be able to get you some more info

Comment: Have a look at this very basic code that I can repeat the error in: http://pastebin.com/3Mixy6aT. Does this work fine for you?

Comment: The pastebin link has errors as mentioned in Joel's answer, is there any code behind also in use?

Comment: I've created a very simple web application to demonstrate the error I'm facing: http://www.mediafire.com/?8r222x5qim6cwrm. If you don't get an error in this project when using Page=0, I guess that means it's a problem with my version of the DataPager control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is new in v4.0. I cannot reproduce it  using v3.5. It appears to be a known bug in ASP.NET 4.0, but it is hard to find clear references via Google.

Rather than override the `SetPageProperties` of `ListView`, I created an event handler for the `OnInit` event of `DataPager`, which checks the relevant parameter of the query string. From my testing, the only thing that causes an exception is when the page number parameter was zero or negative. In that case, I force the data pager to ignore the query string (by setting the `QueryStringField` to null). This in turn will cause the data pager to default to the first page.

Here's the code:

```
    protected void DataPager_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var dp = sender as DataPager;
        if (dp == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("This Event handler only works for DataPager web controls.");
        }

        string strPageNum = Request.QueryString[dp.QueryStringField];
        if (strPageNum == null) return;  // param not there, DataPager will use default

        int pageNum = -1;
        if (int.TryParse(strPageNum, out pageNum) && pageNum > 0)
        {
            return; // valid page number parameter, let DataPager handle it
        }


        dp.QueryStringField = null; // Force default
    }
```

Of course, you will need to add `OnInit="DataPager_Init"` to the markup for the `<asp:DataPager>` web control.  Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, works beautifull! Any idea why I have the error, in spite of using .Net 4.0? BTW, I have restarted the bounty on the question, so that I can award it to you. You deserve it ;) SO will only let me award it in 23 hours (since it'd expired). Will award it then. Cheers.

Comment: @Perpetually By "new in 4.0" I meant that the unwanted behavior is new in v4.0. I don't want to call it a bug without knowing more, but it sure seems like one to me.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I see - that does sound very strange indeed.

Comment: I've just experienced something very similar when upgrading a 3.5 application to run on 4.0. I'd expect this would actually be classed as an 'enhancement' though rather than a bug. Frustrating really as we'd used -1 to show all items on one page

Comment: having said that, 4.0 is supposed to be backwards compatible. I'd expect to see this issue mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656.aspx#aspnet

Comment: This solution will force the datapager to NOT use a querystring anymore.
By setting this to nothing " dp.QueryStringField = null; " , you force it into the javascript postback mode!

Comment: Had to downvote this as this method merely switches away from using a querystring and is not a solution for catching an invalid page (and retain querystring mode). There, unfortunately, is no way to catch this in DotNet 4.* using the DataPager control - it's an unresolved bug (so you must write your own control). It's a futile effort. MS is abandoning ASP.Net webforms for MVC, regardless, so this will never be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As with others who have commented, I am unable to reproduce your error. If the `Page` parameter in the query string is invalid in any way (e.g. parameter missing, number out of range, non-numeric data), the `DataPager` ignores it and defaults to page 1.

Also, the sample code at http://pastebin.com/3Mixy6aT throws an exception, but for a different reason. Specifically, there is no `LayoutTemplate` with a server control that has id `itemPlaceholder`. I added a layout template, and the data pager works fine, regardless of the page number you give it.  For example:

```
      <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
          <LayoutTemplate>
              <asp:Literal ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
               <br />
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
              <%#Eval("UserID") %><br />
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:ListView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
           ConnectionString="Data Source=..."
           SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users]">
      </asp:SqlDataSource>

      Page:
      <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1" 
          PageSize="5" QueryStringField="Page">
          <Fields>
              <asp:NumericPagerField />
          </Fields>
      </asp:DataPager>
```

Note that the `SetPageProperties` method is a member of `DataPager`, not `ListView`. Interestingly, if you use this method to set an invalid row number (e.g. -1) in the code behind, you will get an "argument out of range error". Moreover, this exception is thrown even if you are missing the `LayoutTemplate`, so it will mask any problems you may have with your layout template.

My conclusion is that your problem has nothing to do with the `Page` parameter in your query string. I recommend that you make sure that you `LayoutTemplate` is correct, and that you are not calling `SetPageProperites` in the code behind. (If you really need to set the page properties for some other reason, you can post a new question to deal with that.)

Comment: That's strange - I didn't encounter an exception without the LayoutTemplate. I have added the LayoutTemplate, but I am still getting errors when I put page = 0 in the querystring (there's nothing in the code-behind file). Maybe I have a different version of the control?

Comment: @Perpetually - What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: It should be version 4.0, though the project was initially imported from a 2.0 project. Is there any way to find out for sure?

Comment: Nevermind. I got your download from mediafire, looks like 4.0.

Comment: Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Nope, no idea how to flush the cache, and yes, I had rebuilt the project multiple times. I have the problem on my local machine, as well as the production server. I'm guessing when I publish to my development machine, the faulty control gets published as well?

Comment: Publishing will copy WebApplication1.dll to the target server. However, if you are having a problem with the GAC on your local machine, that will not affect the target server(s). Since you are having the problem on several machines, flushing the GAC (local machine) probably won't help. And you generally want to avoid flushing the GAC on a production server. I'll dig some more and see what I can find. BTW, I downloaded and built the code you posted on mediafire. It runs fine.

Comment: You're welcome. OK, I duplicated the problem using your WebApplication1 DLL (i.e. without building). If I figure out what is wrong, I will post as a new answer. If I can't figure it out, I'll just post a comment here. BTW, am doing this for myself too, because I am learning some new things from the exercise.